# Open www.google.com instead of www.google.co.in in firefox using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, cookies, proxy, selenium-webdriver, google-search

I need to open www.google.com instead of the localized version of google while running my tests using Selenium Webdriver(with Python bindings).
Using a proxy is one option but when I use a proxy the page loads very slowly. Is there any alternative to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

just open http://www.google.com/ncr instead of http://www.google.com, this will do No Country Redirect (or whatever NCR stands for)